# When running a Linux command in the background, is there any reason to put white space before the ampersand?

Tags: linux, asynchronous, ampersand

I recently saw that you can execute a script, application, or command in the background using the ampersand **without** white space in front of &. Does this do something different than using whitespace?

For example:
firefox&
seems to function the same as:
firefox &

Is there a specific requirement or reason to put the white space before the ampersand?

Comment: it depends, on commands parameters you give or not.

Comment: StackOverflow is dedicated to helping solve programming code problems.  Your Q **may be**  more appropriate for [su]  , but read their help section regarding on-topic questions . AND please read [Help On-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/On-topic) and [Help How-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/Help/How-to-ask) before posting more Qs here.  Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

The [POSIX shell grammar](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html) treats `&` the same way as `;`:

```
separator_op     : '&'
                 | ';'
                 ;
```

There is therefore no difference between writing `foo&` and `foo &`, just like there is no difference between `foo;` and `foo ;`